# sql server query on odbc get error - [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state 0

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

Since last upgrade of ms-access while using pass through query results in this error:

> sql server query on odbc get error - [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
>   Invalid cursor state 0

(Office Access 365 version 1911, while return records on query is true...)

After **downgrade Access version**- the problem solved...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office365-proplus-by-date

[image]

Any one got over solution?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/odbc-call-failed-microsoftodbc-driver-manager/de303266-7e6a-45a8-ac61-1164bec89e98?tab=AllReplies)

> This is a bug introduced in Office Version 1912, which is an Insiders
>   build, so most users, on Monthly Channel (still on Version 1911),
>   won't see this.
>
> This will be fixed in the next release of Version 1912, which might be
>   a re-release for Insiders, or it may not be until it becomes the next
>   Monthly Channel build in a few weeks.
>
> In the meantime, the easiest workaround is likely to switch to the
>   Monthly Channel build until the fix is released.
>
> Shane Groff
>
> Access Engineering